# Highcharts map graphic in a web application doesn't work

Tags: dictionary, highcharts

I would like to integrate highmap graphic (type map) in a web application with other different types graphics.

To make tests, I have pasted the code to display 2 graphics (1 bubble, 1 map) and all the files called to make it work (js, css, etc...) are directly the application files.

In this page, everything goes right : both graphics  are normally displayed.

But, when I reintegrate the same code in the application, this doesn't work anymore. I have tried to display the extern page through an iframe and this works fine.

I would like to find a way to debug this because I don't really know which direction to follow.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to supply us any live demo of that ?

Comment: I can show you these pictures:
Graphics on external page :
[link](http://imageshack.com/a/img538/2842/kvgMm5.png)

Graphics throuh an iframe on the application
[link](http://imageshack.com/a/img538/2141/lXG7Wr.png)

Graphic that should be displayed on the application
[link](http://imageshack.com/a/img538/5374/DPWvhu.png)

Js errors of the previous image
[link](http://imageshack.com/a/img633/7218/TjJzmK.jpg)

Comment: Each errors refers to subpage, where you have explanaintion. Check your loading files order, becaue it seems that you miss map.js file

Comment: The order (both on the application and on the external file) is

highmaps.js
highcharts.js
highcharts-more.js
exporting.js

Comment: If you have highcharts, you should load map.js not highmaps.js. More inforamtio please visit [this page](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/getting-started)